# editable json and setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I try to display bunch of json object using map within a textarea. User can edit it, but I have to validate all the json is valid before it get pass to my server.

I'm having problem parsing it, where should I parse it? Parsing it on the onChange it a way but it's dangerous.

```
onChange = (e, idx) => {
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.map((o,i) => {
        if(i === idx){
          return JSON.parse(e.target.value) //dangerous
        }
        return o
      })
    })
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/880414y0m0

Comment: Then use `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Please save your code sandbox. it showing the deafult code

Comment: @str can elaborate more? try catch within onChange?

Comment: @stack26 thanks, didn't notice that, saved my codesandbox

Comment: Just put it around the `JSON.parse` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
onChange = (e, idx) => {

    let  dataToSet = [...this.state.data]
    let error = false
    try {
      dataToSet = dataToSet.map((o,i) => {
        if(i === idx){
          return JSON.parse(e.target.value) //dangerous
        }
        return o
      })
    } catch(e) {
       error = true
    }
    this.setState({
      data: dataToSet,
      error,
    })
 }
```

Here is the codesandbox link which handles those scenario. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3833ovr11q)